# grabbing website from email address in php

Tags: php, mysql

How to pull website name from email address in php/mysql.
Exploding is too expensive here ,as i have to do it for several thousands data inside db

```
original data
test@example.com
test@example1.com

needed data
example.com
example1.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getDomain( $email ) {
    return substr( $email, strpos( $email, '@' ) + 1 );
}

$website = getDomain( 'test@example.com' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the index of the @ by using `strrpos` and then substring the remaining part using `substr`.

```
$atpos = strrpos($eaddress, '@');
$domain = substr($eaddress, $atpos + 1);
```

Comment: You were missing a closing parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Use [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to find the `@` and [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the part after it.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(... as $email) {
  $domains[] = substr($email, strpos('@', $email) + 1);
}
```

This should work nicely - note that there is no validation for `strpos` returning false, indicating that the line does not contain the @ symbol.

Answer (score 1):

If you have long list of email in Database then its better to trim website from database rather than on web server Query should be

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(email_field, '@', -1) FROM email_table;
```

because  of **-1** right side string would be return after first occurrence of **@**

Hopes that Helps

Comment: "its better to trim website from database rather than on web server" - Are you sure? Why?

Comment: yes if you already have list in Database, look first you query DB then trim record on web server(need to iterate all records again) 2 Steps, while if you trim it in query only 1 Step, it is too much efficient than load list on web server than trim it there.

Comment: I'm asking because you say it's "better" without defining "better". There is not necessarily two iterations needed to trim the addresses on the web server - you may trim it when fetching the rows. I actually think this is a microoptimization and it doesn't matter that much where you do the trimming, but in some cases it may be costly because it's cheaper and easier to scale the web layer than the db layer. So the definition of *better* may vary.

Comment: Note: I'm not saying it's bad to do work in the database system, Ḯ'm just saying that it's not always better. I have no idea what way to go in this case, but as I said: it's probably microoptimzation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just for something a bit different: `preg_match` domain name capture:

```
<?php
  $address = array("test@example.com","test@example.co.uk","test2@ez.example.com");
  foreach ($address as $email) {
   preg_match(";\b.+@([a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2,}))\b;", $email,$matches);
   echo $matches[1];
   echo "\n";
  }
?>
```

Output:

```
example.com
example.co.uk
ez.example.com
```

Comment: I'm usually rather fluent in regexes, but this is almost uncomprehensible! Why do you explicitly state a lot of characters before the `@`?

Comment: @EmilVikström No other reason than because I can, really! Tried to be as specific to the RFC 2822 as possible, for valid ASCII email address I'll pare it down though.